# Maximum recursion depth exceeded while using Slither

Tags: python, python-3.x, solidity, smartcontracts, static-analysis

I'm getting `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` when trying to analyze my contract using Slither. Anyone knows how to sort this out? Thanks!

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 744, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 87, in process_all
    ) = process_single(compilation, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 70, in process_single
    slither = Slither(target, ast_format=ast, **vars(args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/slither.py", line 118, in __init__
    parser.parse_contracts()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slither_compilation_unit_solc.py", line 489, in parse_contracts
    self._analyze_third_part(contracts_to_be_analyzed, libraries)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slither_compilation_unit_solc.py", line 596, in _analyze_third_part
    self._analyze_variables_modifiers_functions(contract)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slither_compilation_unit_solc.py", line 669, in _analyze_variables_modifiers_functions
    contract.analyze_content_functions()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/contract.py", line 404, in analyze_content_functions
    function_parser.analyze_content()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/function.py", line 282, in analyze_content
    self._parse_cfg(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/function.py", line 1071, in _parse_cfg
    self._remove_incorrect_edges()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/function.py", line 1275, in _remove_incorrect_edges
    self._fix_try(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/function.py", line 1150, in _fix_try
    self._fix_catch(son, end_node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/function.py", line 1158, in _fix_catch
    self._fix_catch(son, end_node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/function.py", line 1158, in _fix_catch
    self._fix_catch(son, end_node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/function.py", line 1158, in _fix_catch
    self._fix_catch(son, end_node)
  [Previous line repeated 1481 more times]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/function.py", line 1153, in _fix_catch
    if not node.sons:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: The issue is caused when your contracts have a try/catch block. No solution has been found to this